# Linear bound on maximal rectangle in a permutation

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry, extremal-combinatorics

Given $n$ coloured squares in an $n$ by $n$ square board of unit squares, one in each row and column (which we will call a permutation), let the minimum area (over all permutations) of the largest rectangle that can be drawn with sides parallel to the edges of the big square without touching a coloured square be $f(n)$.  Does there exist real $c$ such that $f(n)<cn$ for all sufficiently large $n$?

It would seem easier to start with the continuous version, with $n$ points in a unit square and the anologous bound of $c/n$.

Context: This was an old question that I asked:

[Maximal rectangle in a permutation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/527275/101039)

where I was attempting to find bounds on the size of the largest rectangle that could be found in a permutation ($n$ squares each in a different row and column) in an $n\times n$ square board.  Recently a friend of mine proved an upper bound of the form $O(n\log n)$ via a greedy algorithm on the related question of finding the largest rectangle parallel to the sides not touching any of $n$ points placed in a unit square.  The question of a lower bound that is better than linear, however, still seems rather difficult.

Comment: What are the values of $f(n)$ for the first values of $n$ ?

Comment: The values for 5,6,7,8,10,13 seem to be 4,6,8,8,12,16 respectively, as far as I can remember.   There is a construction for 34 on 25 by 25 too

Comment: In general for these small values the crude $O(n^{3/2})$ construction gives better values than other more intelligent attempts